# Inserting a character in front of every instance of a certain character in vi

Tags: vi

I have a dataset that I have put into excel but every time there isn't a data point for a certain instance, a -1 is put there instead, which is messing up the graph I am trying to make.  I did some research and people said that if you put an asterix (*) before a data point in excel, it will exclude that point from the graph.  What can I type into the ios vi that will insert an asterix before every instance of -1? Thanks!

Comment: Why dont you replace like `:%s/-1/*-1/g`? It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are working with a CSV file, then you should be able to distinguish `-1` from `-1.4` or `1e-1` by seeing if the value is comma separated.

To make the pattern easier to match, I would first modify the file to insert `,` to the beginning and end of all lines.

```
:%s/.*/,&,/
```

Then, apply the substitution of `-1` to `*-1` two times. The second time is to deal with two `-1` values in a row.

```
:%s/,-1,/,*-1,/g
:%s/,-1,/,*-1,/g
```

Then, remove the extra `,` from the beginning and end.

```
:%s/^,\(.*\),$/\1/
```